# Change the color values of the image in for loop using python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matplotlib

Fig.1 Polygon with black background

[image: Polygon with black background]

Fig.2 desired output

[image: without for-loop]

Fig.3 Input

[image]

There are some images with a black background and white polygon inside (fig.1) since some lines of the polygon are not straight the value of colors in some pixels are not 0 or 255. I tried to change the color values to 0 for outside of the polygon and 255 for inside. This code is working perfectly for single image to change the colors (fig.2) but when I put it in the loop for all images (1024) it's not changing some values (fig 3) for instance please see pixel (137,588) in figs 1 and 2.

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as spio
import numpy as np

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
num_geo=1024
## Load coordinates

mat = spio.loadmat('coordinateXY.mat', squeeze_me=True)
coord = mat['coordxy']*10

for i in range(num_geo):
    geo = coord[:, :, i]
    print(coord[:, :, i])
    fig = plt.figure(num_geo,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
    polygon = plt.Polygon(coord[:, :, i],color='w')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
    plt.savefig('figure/%d.jpg' % i, dpi=my_dpi)

    # Save as numpy file
    img_mat = io.imread('figure/%d.jpg' % i)
    np.save('img_mat.npy', img_mat)
    data = np.load('img_mat.npy')

    # # adjust the colors and save the revised version
    data1 = np.where(data<180, 0, data)
    data2 = np.where(data1>185, 255, data1)
    arr=data2
    plt.imsave('figureRev/%d.jpg' % i,arr)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Do you have some example input/output, a [mcve]?

Comment: The image you see is without using the loop and if click on number 2 you can see the image which is gendered inside the for-loop.

Comment: Please try to improve your question - I have no idea what the problem is! I don't see any images with a black background and white polygons inside... I only see red and blue rectangles with white digits inside. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I add the image and tried to improve the question.

Comment: I still don't understand. What has the polygon with the black background got to do with the red and blue rectangles? What is the input? What is the correct output of your program?

Comment: My input is multiple images with 600X600 pixels which fig.1 is one of them. Since the the images are black and white therefore, the color values of images should be zero or 255. But in pixels at edges you can see other color values(figure 3). The output should be image just with values zero and 255 like fig.2. please note that fig 2 and 3 are matrix of color values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see now!

It's either because you used JPEG which is **lossy** and allowed to change your data - in which case try PNG format which is **lossless**.

Or, it's because the diagonal line has been drawn with *"anti-aliasing"* [Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing)which you can turn off if you don't want it. Alternatively, you can threshold your data at say 127 to ensure all values below and equal become zero and all values above become 255.